# Word order while using "to be interested in"-which one is correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

How is the correct sentence, while using *to be interested in* with a *little* or *a little bit* (is this right?)

> - I am interested a little in football.
> - I am a little interested in football.
> - I am interested in football a little.

Can we say "a little" or it is better to use "a little bit"? Is this a word choice or strict rule?

Comment: Your first and third options are identical, but it doesn’t really matter, ’cause #2 is the better option. Still doesn’t flow quite right, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say option#2. To be sure, I would replace "a little" with "quite", "not" or "very". It wouldn't fit with #1 and #3.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking rather "I am interested in football a little bit, but I was thinking as well : " I am a little bit interested in ...football e.g. Is this a little bit better than a little?